# Custom Shipping Charge in Magento

Tags: magento

I am just wondering with the custom shipping rates in my magento store. My Rules is to make the shipping charges as per below structure:

For the Product Weight:
  0   - 1KG : $7(Shipping rate) ,  1KG - 3KG : $10,   3KG - 5KG : $15

Now if someone Order for 100KG weight product then the Shipping charges must be $300 (100 / 5 =20, then 20 x $15 = $300) and same for the 102KG then it should be $310. (for 20 x $15 = 300 and reminder is 2KG which falls under the 1-3KG range. So $10 would be added on the $300).

So is there anyway that i can config these on the CSV file or need to do something coding. So please suggest and help me out.

Comment: You should have to use a special extension or you write something like that otherwise you need to modify shipping calculation before checkout.

Answer (score 0):

With standard Magento you can do this, but only if you do long hand with table rates carrier, i.e you would need a row for each weight range you wish to change the price, its going to be a pretty big table.

Otherwise extension route or custom coding.